# Integrating ads into an android game using Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have integrated yandex ads sdk into my application and then initialized the SDK in my main activity. I'm using this code at the end to run my app:

```
// Set by content src="index.html" in config.xml
loadUrl(launchUrl);
```

The problem is that the game starts, but the ads are not shown. When I remove loadUrl(launchUrl), the application opens with an ad banner. I don’t use an XML file, I create a banner programmatically.

Can anyone help me what am I missing? I would really appreciate any help.
Here is the Main Activity java file:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.yandex.mobile.ads.banner.BannerAdEventListener;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.banner.BannerAdSize;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.banner.BannerAdView;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.common.AdRequest;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.common.AdRequestError;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.common.ImpressionData;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.common.MobileAds;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, () -> {
            // now you can use ads
            Log.d("my log" ,"ini");
        });

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        // Create a banner ad
        final BannerAdView bannerAd = new BannerAdView(this);
        bannerAd.setAdSize(BannerAdSize.stickySize(this, 600));
        bannerAd.setAdUnitId("demo-banner-yandex");
        bannerAd.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                // Methods in the AdRequest.Builder class can be used here to specify individual options settings.
                .build();
        
        layout.addView(bannerAd, adParams);
        bannerAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        setContentView(layout);

        bannerAd.setBannerAdEventListener(new BannerAdEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Log.d("my log", "Yandex ADS Loaded");
                // If this callback occurs after the activity is destroyed, you
                // must call destroy and return or you may get a memory leak.
                // Note `isDestroyed` is a method on Activity.
                if (isDestroyed() && bannerAd != null) {
                    bannerAd.destroy();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull final AdRequestError adRequestError) {
                // Ad failed to load with AdRequestError.
                Log.d("my log", "Yandex ADS ERROR");
                // Attempting to load a new ad from the onAdFailedToLoad() method is strongly discouraged.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftApplication() {
                // Called when user is about to leave application (e.g., to go to the browser), as a result of clicking on the ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onReturnedToApplication() {
                // Called when user returned to application after click.
            }

            @Override
            public void onImpression(@Nullable ImpressionData impressionData) {
                // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
            }
        });
        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

I also tried to show the banner via XML file, but the result is the same.